# Generate a public key with a predefined modulus and exponent

Tags: python, rsa, public-key-encryption, encryption-asymmetric, jwk

```
"n": "rKZ-1zdz_CoLekSynOtyWv6cPSSkV28Kb9kZZHyYL-yhkKnH_bHl8OpWiGxQiKP0ulLRIaq1IhSMetkZ8FfXH-iptIDu4lPb8gt0HQYkjcy3HoaKRXBw2F8fJQO4jQ-ufR4l-E0HRqwLywzdtAImNWmju3A4kx8s0iSGHGSHyE4EUdh5WKt-NMtfUPfB5v9_2bC-w6wH7zAEsI5nscMXnvz1u8w7g2_agyhKSK0D9OkJ02w3I4xLMlrtKEv2naoBGerWckKcQ1kBYUh6WASPdvTqX4pcAJi7Tg6jwQXIP1aEq0JU8C0zE3d33kaMoCN3SenIxpRczRzUHpbZ-gk5PQ",
"e": "AQAB",
```

How can I generate a public key from these values? Preferable via python or Linux programs. I'm sorry if the question is nonsense because of invalid values.

The source is [here](https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you can use [Python-JOSE](https://github.com/mpdavis/python-jose)

What you got there in your link is a [JSON Web Key Set (JWKS)](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/json-web-tokens/json-web-key-sets), a JSON formated array of [JSON Web Keys (JWK)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7517).

`n` and `e` are the modulus and exponent of a RSA public key.

The function `jwk.construct` can directly create a key from a JWK. The key can then be used e.g. to verify a JWT (`key.verify`).

You can also use `jwt.decode` like shown in the code below and pass the JWK directly, or in PEM format.

```py
from jose import jwk
from jose.utils import base64url_decode

token = "eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6IlctNjduZWt0WVRjOEpWWVBlV0g1c1dlN1JZVm5uMFN5NzQxZjhUT0pfQWMifQ.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiYWRtaW4iOnRydWUsImlhdCI6MTUxNjIzOTAyMn0.hiKxeC66LIyVKOXjiOk7iScFPy_5-ATw7hEfqGij8sBZmwXAeTPT5BRFYHitFKSXomGqmy_63LLvg4zbhcTTmNf8XIeDAuLsC32soO5woSByisswWHVf8BgxMkI_FPW_oEtEQ8Xv3FL_1rF9j9Oy3jIjgjqhFhXUtsSQWAeuGYH-OQljFwiuO5Bqexcw-H71OEWvQLQof_6KJ0viJyte8QEwEVridyO834-ppHzeaoW2sTvZ22ZNfxPCew0Ul2V_TxHTtO7ZuJCZ81EmeIV6dYJ2GrYh3UN1x1PHy4-tEn-PL4otlaO3PYOcXfCHxHa6xtPsquzPZJnB1Vq8zULLfQ"

rsa_key = {
    "kty": "RSA",
    "kid": "W-67nektYTc8JVYPeWH5sWe7RYVnn0Sy741f8TOJ_Ac",
    "use": "sig",
    "alg": "RS256",
    "n": "kFpGoVmBmmKepvBQiwq3hU9lIAuGsAPda4AVk712d3Z_QoS-5veGp4yltnyEFYyX867GOKDpbH7OF2uIjDg4-FPZwbuhiMscbkZzh25SQmfRtCT5ocUloQiopBcNAE-sd1p-ayUJWjhPrFoBrBLZHYxVEjY4JrWevQDj7kSeX7eJpud_VuZ77TNoIzj7d_iUuJUUlqF1ZF540igHKoVJJ6ujQLHh4ob8_izUuxX2iDq4h0VN3-uer59GsWw6OHgkOt85TsjMwYbeN9iw_7cNfLEYpSiH-sVHBCyKYQw7f8bKaChLxDRhUUTIEUUjGT9Ub_A3gOXq9TIi8BmbzrzVKQ",
    "e": "AQAB"
}

key = jwk.construct(rsa_key)

message, encoded_sig = token.rsplit('.', 1)
decoded_sig = base64url_decode(encoded_sig + '=' * (4 - len(encoded_sig) % 4)) # looks weird, but without added padding I got errors
res = key.verify(bytes(message, "UTF-8"), decoded_sig)
# jwt.decode(token=token, key=key.to_pem().decode(), algorithms= 'RS256') # with PEM key
payload = jwt.decode(token=token, rsa_key, algorithms= 'RS256') # with JWK
print(res)
print(payload)
```

The result will be:

> True
> {'sub': '1234567890', 'name': 'John Doe', 'admin': True, 'iat': 1516239022}

which means the token could be verified with that key.

Comment: Thanks!
Can you explain please why a right key (`key.to_pem()`) returns `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

`from jose import jwt`
token: https://stackoverflow.com/q/65909233/14190526 (too long to past into a comment)
`jwt.decode(token=text, key=key.to_pem(), algorithms=algorithms)`

Comment: see my edited answer: with `key=key.to_pem().decode()` the error is gone.

Comment: Yeah, but another error occurs: `jose.exceptions.JWTClaimsError: Invalid audience`. I have the audience in credentials but don't know how to pass it

Comment: you can set a parameter like this : `audience = allowed_aud,`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62822313/how-to-validate-es384-jwt-signature-with-x-and-y-coordinate-in-python/62823271#62823271

Comment: just now I checked it and it's working, it's also requiring an `access_token` for some reason, but I  have it in credentials. Some peoples (like I'm) don't vote for their own question because they are not experts and it may lead to confusion because other peoples will think that question has upvoted by experts.
Now my question is completely solved, thank u.
BTW did you know how preferable to store public keys locally or check online? If locally: is these keys are equivalent or it will be every time signed with another key and therefore I will need to iterate to get out a current key?

Comment: you can cache the key locally and if it fails (or the kid doesn't match), fetch again from the certificate endpoint. I think they change the key frequently, but not so often. Regarding voting, it merely tells the answerer and other people that you (or just someone) found it usefull. On some questions with many answers you see the difference, but afterall you never know who voted and why

Comment: A little note about padding from another question: 
"and not coincidentally OAuth is specified to use JWS/JWT which is specified to use the base64url variant from rfc4648 which has exactly those alphabet differences, and no padding -- but 0x010001 doesn't need padding. "
source: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/87820/86538